# How to add large text under an endpoint (not description area)

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swashbuckle

The following screen shot shows where I would like the text to be.  I do not mean the description that is beside the API name, but putting a larger text description under the API name that could hide when collapsed.

I am using Swashbuckle-swagger in .net and can't find a settings to put in description text for a controller.

[image: Screen shot of a swagger page showing new text under endpoint name saying "how do I add text here"]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [XML comments](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments) and give the controller class a summary, or you can use the attribute [SwaggerTag](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#add-tag-metadata) which will put text in the same place.

Comment: The API wasn't wrote in Core :(.